# Positioning problems with IE7 (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I have some problems with a menu on my website.
In  chrome, IE8, safari, FF etc it looks fine.

The only problem I have is IE7.
In IE7 the menu is not at the top of the site.

I have a seperate css file for IE7, but can't find the problem.

My site is http://www.e107webdesign.nl

It's the video menu at the right side of the screen.
It is placing itself at the same level as the news, but it needs to be on the same level as menu 1 and menu 2.

Some help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You are using the XHTML1.1 doctype, which is an XML only application. Are you really serving this as XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the problem cross-browser by floating the sidebar3 **right** instead of left, and adding a **clear** to the art-content div (although it's worth validating your mark-up too).

```
.art-content {clear: left;}
.art-sidebar3 {float: right;}
```

Comment: Thanks John, that fixed the problem!
.art-sidebar3 could still float to the left now. (looks better :-)


Thanks to Rocket I also noticed a part in my css was not closed with a {

Answer (score 0):

You havn't closed all your divs, theres still one open.

Try validating it. http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Frustrating. So is it a div after the news part that isn't closed?